# Ignore JsonDeserializer when deserialising sub classes objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have parent class on which I have specified a custom deserialiser like this -

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class ParentClass {
}
```

I have subclasses extending above class and I don't want those classes to use CustomDeserializer for deserialisation purpose. I know using Will ignore the CustomDeserializer class during serialisation.

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = Child.class)
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}
```

The question is - Is there any other way to tell ObjectMapper or anything else which will ignore this CustomDeserializer without specifically specifying @JsonDeserialize(as = Child.class) on every child class ?

Comment: Maybe you could implement that functionality on the CustomDeserializer itself, so it detects if it is called for deserialization of a child class of the `ParentClass`, and treat it differently - deserialize it as-is?

Comment: You are right but let say I check it inside the CustomDeserializer and then finally calls objectMapper.readValueAs(childClassObject, ChildClass.class). This would cause infinite loop, because objectMapper inherently will use CustomDeserializer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the annotation from the ParentClass and create a new subclass with the annotation. Use this new subclass when you want to deserialize to a ParentClass. As the custom deserialize annotation is on the subclass you can return an instance of ParentClass.

```
public class ParentClass {
    // fields in the ParentClass
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class ParentWithCustomDeserialize extends Parent {
}
```

Then you can simply...

```
Parent parent = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ParentWithCustomDeserialize.class);
```

Comment: looks promising, will try and confirm.

Comment: Problem here is that I will have to make explicit check that if the object class is ParentClass then deserialize as ParentWithCustomDeserialize.class, This will make it more error prone.